# How to restore the sms backup taken to sms.db in android

Tags: java, android

I have taken the backup of all sms in inbox.After that I stored the backup in JSON format in the SD card creting a file SMSJSON.txt. Now I am reading the file from the SD card and parsing the data successfully, but how to write those data again to sms.db . Plz guide me. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean restoreSms(Sms obj) {
    boolean ret = false;
    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("address", obj.getAddress());
        values.put("body", obj.getMsg());
        values.put("read", obj.getReadState());
        values.put("date", obj.getTime());
        Uri temp_sms = mActivity.getContentResolver().insert(
                Uri.parse("content://sms/" + obj.getFolderName()), values);
        ret = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Use this permission in AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```